# Password Protected SQLite Database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to make my db file encrypted so no one can access it without having the password, so first thing came to my mind is using the built in SQLite encryption and here is the code i am using to create a password for a database

```
public void SetPassword(byte[] password)
{
    _dbConnection.SetPassword(password);
}
```

But what really i am surprised about is that any one could easily remove the password and see the content of the database using a very simple code like

```
public void RemovePassword(SQLiteConnection conn)
{
    conn.ChangePassword(null);
}
```

So i was wondering what is the use of that build in encryption if it can be removed that easy ?!. Or am i wrong about something i have mentioned ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Just make sure nobody gets ahold of your database file. Encrypting it in an application on the same machine is pretty much pointless, since if the application can decrypt it, then a user with access to the application can too.

Comment: @minitech : And how that will be done ? The database file must be located any place around my program executable file so any body would get the database file, run the removepassword code on it and he have it !

Comment: Uh, I didn’t propose a solution. I asked why you’re even bothering in the first place.

Comment: @minitech : Because i need my database to be encrypted !!. I am creating a program for a small company that program will need a small database; However, the information in this database must be encrypted so no one could easily come and take the small company's secrets that's all about it

Comment: It’s going to be easy no matter what. How about don’t use SQLite?

Comment: there are no alternatives for a good local database other than SQLite, are there ?. [For The Reason] that the project is not that big that i use a hosted database to hold the data for it, Also i don't like storing data in xml, text files.

Comment: Hosted databases aren’t necessarily just for big projects. If you don’t want everyone to have access to everyone else’s data, maybe it’s appropriate.

Comment: Still it is not an option for my clients to force them to install sql server and all that crap just to run the application so i think any other solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Another reason to require a local database is that the clients are not always connected... quite essential to have a local database if you're application needs to support offline use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the solution is simply :

When a password is set to the database using

```
.SetPassword(password);
```

it can't be simply removed or changed using the changepassword function unless you have legally connected to the database using the old password {Or cracked the database somehow :D}

```
.ChangePassword(password);
```